# Laravel Form Validator for Unique with hasMany Relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I am having a validator bug when try to validate a form where a 'user' can have many 'emails'.  The goal is to make sure that when updating a 'user' the 'emails' all are distinct and unique, but on edits involving two or more 'emails' the validator throws and won't let me proceed with the addition or edit of the user because it sees the emails on the user I am editing, this is only the case when there are two or more 'emails' on the 'user'.

The emails are stored in a separate table with a foreign key 'user_id' that points it back to the user the emails are linked to.

Here is the current rule code

```
$rules += [
                'user' => [
                    'required',
                    Rule::unique('users','name')->ignore($this->user),
                    
                ],
                'emails.*' => [ 
                   'distinct',                
                    Rule::unique('emails','address')->ignore($this->user),
                ],
            ];
```

It will let me add a second 'email' to the user in the edit or add screens, but when trying to edit when there are two or more the validator throws.

Comment: Can you share the error message?

Comment: Please specify the error message next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the name of the column that needs to be ignored in emails table, try this:

```
Rule::unique('emails','address')->ignore($this->user->id, 'user_id')
```